# Communicate different templates on Ansible Tower/AWX Workflow

Tags: templates, ansible, workflow, ansible-awx

I'm working on a Workflow on AWX to run several templates (basically playbooks).
I have created a project that connects to the git to get my playbooks.

Manually they will run one after the other and one of the playbooks will depend on the other. For example the 001 playbook will generate some files that the 002 playbook will need.

```
├── integration
│   ├── 001_get_changes.yml
│   ├── 002_create_json.yml
│   ├── 003_get_owners.yml
│   ├── 004_get_instances.yml
│   ├── 005_check_landscape.yml
│   ├── 006_create_landscape.yml
│   ├── 007_check_environment.yml
│   ├── 008_create_environment.yml
│   ├── _ansible.cfg
│   ├── files
│   ├── vars
│   ├── templates
```

So when I run them with the workflow, they fail.
The message is that 002, is not able to find the files generated by 001.

My question would be, the templates run separated even in the same workflow?
I have added a "Project Sync" between the 2 templates on the workflow, but there were no changes. Is there anyway to get the files from one template to the other?

Thanks

Comment: If you are placing the files in your git ansible project directory, chances are AWX is wipping those files out on every run. This depends on how you have configured your project, how it is updating on every run and if it empties everything before update. Meanwhile, it is not a good idea to rely on this for your workflow. Store those files externally so you are sure you can get them back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help anyone in the future.
It is possible to move information from one template to another in AWX/Ansible Tower.
Its necessary to use **set_stats**. Basically it allows you to store a variable to be consume downstream.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/workflows.html